# Problem redirecting stdout in Node 16's package.json

Tags: node.js, stdout

I have three script targets in my package.json's script section:

```
"schema:generate": "mkdir -p ./dist && typescript-json-schema tsconfig.json --tsNodeRegister --required --strictNullChecks --noExtraProps --refs --aliasRefs WireMessage >dist/tmpschema",
"schema:replace": "cat dist/tmpschema | sed 's:#/definitions/:#/components/schemas/WireMessage/definitions/:g' >dist/swagger.schema.json",
"schema:messages": "cp dist/tmpschema dist/messages.schema.json",
"schema": "yarn run schema:generate && yarn run schema:replace && yarn run schema:messages",
```

However, `yarn run schema` makes `dist/swagger.schema.json` constantly get only half the contents of `dist/tmpschema`. Why?

This works, replacing

```
 >dist/swagger.schema.json
```

with

```
 | tee dist/swagger.schema.json >/dev/null
```

The file is exactly 2^15 bytes, 32 768 of them. WTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node has a bug, so that if the output of a redirect is larger than a short, it's truncated.

Instead use the command `tee`